# How can i get a reference to a QDialog Object?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, reference, qdialog

I'm trying to access elements of a QDialog(in my case DisplayWindow) from another class.

**displaywindow.cpp:**

```
        DisplayWindow::DisplayWindow(QWidget *parent, int devNr) :
            QDialog(parent),
            ui(new Ui::DisplayWindow)
        { 
    ......
```

**the other class.h**:

```
...      
DisplayWindow displaywindow;
            void setDisplaywindow(DisplayWindow dw){
                displaywindow = dw;
            };
            DisplayWindow getDisplayWindow(){
                return displaywindow;
            }
...
```

but the code in "the other class" isnt working. It says the copy operator of DisplayWindow (or QDialog in general) is implicitly delet, so i cant work with the displaywindow Object. Does anybody knows a work around?

Comment: Indeed, you can work with `DisplayWindow` object, but you are not allowed to copy it. Just pass it by reference or by pointer.

Comment: You should handle Qt widgets by pointers and not by value (hence the deleted copy constructor and copy assignment operator).

Comment: @Fareanor could you post an example Code for the "otherClass" ? thx so far

Comment: `DisplayWindow* displaywindow; void setDisplaywindow(DisplayWindow * dw){         displaywindow = dw;
            };` remember to initialize displaywindow to a nullpointer in your class or your constructor.

Comment: @MB1995 Actually we don't know what your "other class" is. Is it supposed to be a `QObject` or not ? Is it supposed to be the parent of the `displaywindow` member or not ? I can't give you a relevant proposal without knowing what you are trying to achieve. Your example is not complete and I don't want to provide an answer only based on assumptions.

Comment: it works now. thanks so much guys. Her is the code (maybe for other Users):     DisplayWindow *displayWindow;
    DisplayWindow *getDisplayWindow(){
        if(displayWindow!=NULL){
        return displayWindow;
        }
    }


    void setDisplaywindow(DisplayWindow *dw){
        this->displayWindow = dw;
    }

Comment: @MB1995 your `getDisplayWindow()` is wrong. If the pointer is `NULL` (you should use `nullptr` instead by the way), your function does not return. It is undefined behaviour if I'm not mistaken. Moreover, if your class is supposed to own the given `DisplayWindow*`, then, your `setDisplayWindow()` is wrong too since it'll leak memory.

Comment: ***is wrong too since it'll leak memory*** Not necessarily, if the parent was set on the passed `DisplayWindow` Qt would handle this by freeing the object when the parent object is freed.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes of course, this is why I specified "if your class is supposed to own it".

Comment: I see I read too fast..